# Adding to an array of lists in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Silly question here, but I'm having trouble finding an example on the web.

I have set up a model on mongoDB that has arrays of objects, like so:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({

    project_id: { type: String },
    item: {
        title: { type: String },
        owners: [{
            first_name : {type: String} ,
            middle_name : {type: String},
            other_name: {type: String},
            last_name: {type: String},
            order: {type: Number, 'default': 1}
        }]
    }
}]
```

So you can see that item is a list of fields. And then `owners` is an array of lists of fields. When I create the project, I'm trying to set the owner like this:

```
var newProject = new Models.Project({
                                'item.title': title,
                                'item.owners[0].last_name': name,
                                'item.owners[0].order': 1
                            });
```

This doesn't generate an error, but the item fields don't get saved either (`item.title` saves fine).
 I tried this too, but it gives me an error:

```
var newProject = new Models.Project({
                                'item.title': title,
                                item.owners.push({last_name: name, order: 1})
                            });
```

How am I supposed to refer to these sub-docs so I can save them?

Comment: I bet you have checked [related mongo-db docs] (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) already but just in case.

Comment: @Alp, yes, I've seen this. I'm missing how to set these values in code. Do you know? `'addresses[0].street' : "fake street"` doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use dot notation in the fields of a new document, create it using the actual structure of the doc instead:

```js
var newProject = new Models.Project({
  item: {
    title: title,
    owners: [{
      last_name: name,
      order: 1
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a simple JSON object. With Javascript, it is quite straight forward. Below code generates the sample object given in the mongoDB doc:

```
var address1 = new Object();
address1.street = "123 Fake Street";
address1.city = "Faketon";
address1.state = "MA";
address1.zip = "12345";

var address2 = new Object();
address2.street = "1 Some other Street";
address2.city = "Boston";
address2.state = "MA";
address2.zip = "12345";




var data = new Object();

data._id = "joe";
data.name = "Joe Bookreader";
var addressArray = new Array();
addressArray.push(address1);
addressArray.push(address2);
data.addresses = addressArray;

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```